# Powershell : Failed To Load Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Utility.dll

Tags: powershell

I don't ve Sql Server installed in my machine but I need the SQLPS module . So I installed below three msi .

```
Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 (SQLSysClrTypes.msi)
Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Shared Management Objects (SharedManagementObjects.msi)
Microsoft® Windows PowerShell Extensions for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 (PowerShellTools.ms
```

Then I tried importing SQLPS module but I got error

```
Importing SQLPS module.
The assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Utility' was not loaded because no assembly with that name was found.
```

I verified and I found this assemby is present under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies` but not under GAC .
So requesting you to please suggest me what I shd do ? I am not getting any clue . Should I copy the assembly to GAC ?

Comment: is .net 4 installed on the box? this is a pre-req

Comment: Yes .Net Framework 4 is installed

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the native client as well?

> Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client (sqlncli.msi)

Comment: I installed but I am getting the same error .Is there any other way around ?

Comment: What's the OS?  I'll test it out

Comment: I am using 2012 Server R2 . I can see the dll at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies" but not under GAC . Can I point to the above path anyway ? I ve powershell V4

Comment: It's resolved now . I tried uninstalling everything and re installed . After it imported SQLPS module . Thanks for your help